# JavaScript create objects in for-loop

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm making a `canvas` game in JavaScript and have some trouble saving the data. I'm placing images on the canvas with a for-loop and I want to save information for each image in objects. For each image an object.

```
function CreateBlocks(){
    for(var i = 0; i <= blocks; i++){
        var img   = new Image();
        img.src   = "/images/Block.png";

        blockObject = {
            x:    x, 
            y:    y, 
            points:  10
         }
         ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);

         x += 100;
         y += 100;
    }
}
```

Now this obviously overwrites the `blockObject` everytime it loops. I tried adding to loop value to the name of the object like `block[i]Object` or `blockObject[i]` but that returns syntax errors.

I could just create a single dimension array for each value, but that seems rather messy to me. How can I create the objects in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `blockObjects` array, your second idea, using the `blockObject[i]` syntax will work:

```
var blockObjects=[];

function CreateBlocks(){
    for(var i = 0; i <= blocks; i++){
        var img   = new Image();
        img.src   = "/images/Block.png";

        blockObjects[i] = {
            x:    x, 
            y:    y, 
            points:  10
        };
        ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);

        x += 100;
        y += 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply use an array and push the new object each time:

```
function CreateBlocks(){
    var arr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i <= blocks; i++){
        var img   = new Image();
        img.src   = "/images/Block.png";

        arr.push({
            x:    x, 
            y:    y, 
            points:  10
         });

         ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);

         x += 100;
         y += 100;
    }
}
```